# How do I cast from int to generic type Integer?

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm relatively new to Java and am used to generics in C# so have struggled a bit with this code. Basically I want a generic method for getting a stored Android preference by key and this code, albeit ugly, works for a Boolean but not an Integer, when it blows up with a ClassCastException. Can anyone tell me why this is wrong and maybe help me improve the whole routine (using wildcards?)?

```
    public static <T> T getPreference(Class<T> argType, String prefKey, T defaultValue,
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {

    ...

    try {
        if (argType == Boolean.class) {
            Boolean def = (Boolean) defaultValue;
            return argType.cast(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(prefKey, def));
        } else if (argType == Integer.class) {
            Integer def = (Integer) defaultValue;
            return argType.cast(new Integer(sharedPreferences.getInt(prefKey, def)));
        } else {
            AppGlobal.logWarning("getPreference: Unknown type '%s' for preference '%s'. Returning default value.",
                    argType.getName(), prefKey);
            return defaultValue;
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        AppGlobal.logError("Cast exception when reading pref %s. Using default value.", prefKey);
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

My calling code is:

```
        mAccuracy = GlobalPreferences.getPreference(Integer.class, prefKey, mAccuracy, sharedPreferences);
```

Here is the Android code for getInt():

```
public int getInt(String key, int defValue) {
        synchronized (this) {
            Integer v = (Integer)mMap.get(key);
            return v != null ? v : defValue;
        }
    }
```

I've tried various ways - using the native int, casting to an Integer, but nothing works.

Comment: Note that I have solved this. See my answer below. The preference itself is being stored as a string and it is the Android code that is erroring. Thanks

Comment: You can't return an `Integer` data type for this method, can you? I mean, the method's signature indicates `int` and not `Integer`....

Comment: That's why I said: "I've tried various ways - using the native int, casting to an Integer, but nothing works." The issue is that the map.get cannot return an int from a ListPreference array, which is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the preference I'm trying to read is stored as a string so the cast exception is coming from inside the Android code not mine. Thanks for your help. But as I am a Java-newbie, if you think there is anything generally wrong with my routine, please teach me a better way.

Comment: The API specifically state that all of the `getType` methods from `SharedPreferences` throw a `ClassCastException` if you attempt to fetch a preference with a name that is not of the same type as the type corresponding to the `getType` method.

Comment: That's right. My next question is how do you have a ListPreference whose values are an array of ints.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest:

```
Integer i = new Integer(42);
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken by your question and what you need to accomplish, this should work given the input is an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. That was my original code. In fact, I am going to edit the sample to show that. Thanks

Comment: I corrected my sample thanks and showed the Android source being called.

Comment: I assumed you've also tried: `return new Integer(sharedPreferences.getInt(prefKey, def));` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a bunch of functions with the same name that take a different type for the default, and let the compiler figure it out.  Java really ties your hands when working with types, especially primitive types.

```
public function int getPreference( String key , int missing ) { return sharedPreferences.getInt( key , missing ); }
public function boolean getPreference( String key , boolean missing ) { return sharedPreferences.getBoolean( key , missing ); }
public function String getPreference( String key , String missing ) { return sharedPreferences.getString( key , missing ); }
```

Edit:

If you are trying to get an object (not primitive) regardless of the type, you can use:

```
public function Object getPreference( String key , Object missing ) { return sharedpreferences.contains( key ) ? sharedPreferences.getAll().get( key ) : missing; }
```

If you are trying to get a specific type like int regardless of what is stored, you can use:

```
public function int getPreference( String key , int missing ) {
    int result = missing;
    Object value = sharedpreferences.contains( key ) ? sharedPreferences.getAll().get( key ) : null;
    if ( value instanceof Integer ) result = ((Integer)value).intValue();
    if ( value instanceof Boolean ) result = ((Boolean)value).booleanValue() ? 1 : 0;
    // repeat for every other primitive wrapper type you care about
    return result;
}
```

If you are trying to get a result only if it is a certain type, you can use something like:

```
public function Object getPreference( Class inRequire , String key , Object missing ) {
    Object value = sharedpreferences.contains( key ) ? sharedPreferences.getAll().get( key ) : null;
    if ( !( value instanceof inRequire ) ) {
        value = null;
    }
    return ( value == null ) ? missing : value;
}
```

Comment: I thought that that was generics were all about :) I'd rather use generics if possible. But if I can't, I'll do what you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Java is not flexible like other languages, and primitives are not objects so they cannot mix in return types or function arguments.  You can return an Object or a specific primitive like int or boolean but it has to be decided at compile time.

Comment: Thanks - that is useful but it is still returning a Object, isn't it? not a strongly typed object.