# How to retrieve preferences in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am making an app that counts down from a time (e.g. 1 min) and then sends a text message to somebody. I am using preferences so that the user can set the time, phone number and message, but I don't know how to make it so that the timer,number and message variables are the ones set in the preferences and not the default ones. Here is the code I have so far.

```
package com.countdowntimer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

        public class CountdownTimer extends Activity implements OnClickListener
            {
                private MalibuCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
                private long timeElapsed;
                private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
                private Button startB;
                private TextView text;
                private TextView timeElapsedView;

                private final long startTime =     30000 ; //I want this to be the value from the preferences
                private final long interval =    1000 ;

                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                    {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_countdown_timer);


                        startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
                        startB.setOnClickListener(this);

                        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
                        timeElapsedView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeElapsed);
                        countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
                        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));
                    }

                public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if (!timerHasStarted)
                            {
                                countDownTimer.start();
                                timerHasStarted = true;
                                startB.setText("Start Timer");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                countDownTimer.cancel();
                                timerHasStarted = false;
                                startB.setText("Stop Timer");
                            }
                    }

                // CountDownTimer class
                public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
                    {

                        public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
                            {
                                super(startTime, interval);
                            }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                            {
                                text.setText("Time's up!");
                            timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));
                            sendSMS("07772417392", "The timer has finished!"); //These should also be the values from the preferences
                            }

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                            {
                                text.setText("Time remaining:" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
                                timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed/1000));
                            }
                }

                private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String Message) {

                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, Message, null, null);
                }
        }
```

I have looked at using SharedPreferences and PreferenceManager etc. but all the examples I look at don't really help me.

EDIT: Have added in some extra code (see below) it has no errors in it but whenever I try and start the timer the app force closes and I don't know why.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                 String timerLength = prefs.getString("timerLength","");
                 TextView timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.showTimer);
                 timer.setText(timerLength);
```

Answer (score 3):

With `Preferences`, you have a `Key/Value` relationship.  You set the `Key` that you would like to store the value under, and then later on you give the `SharedPreference` that `Key` and it will spit out the stored `Value` for you.

So, in my application part of my Preference XML looks like:

```
<EditTextPreference
            android:key="username"
            android:summary="@string/usernameSummary"
            android:title="@string/username" />
```

I can later access the value that the user inputs by doing something like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = preferences.getString("username", ""); //"" is the default String to return if the preference isn't found
```

So I am using the `Key` "username" to get the `Value` that the user stored.

Comment: @Harry12345 what does the stacktrace say when it crashes?  And what is the value of timerLength before you put it into setText()?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a very complete question.  Where are you reading the preferences?  Where are you writing them?  Are you using a PreferenceActivity?  Bear in mind that PreferenceActivity can only handle string values -- if you try to store any other kind of value, PreferenceActivity will crash.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3030933/338479

Comment: The value of timerLength is set to 1 at the start but can be changed. Does "1" count as a string or an int then??

Comment: @Harry12345 If it is inside the quotations then it should be treated as a String.  But you still haven't even said what the error is.

Comment: It comes up with a whole load of error messages so not sure which one is the main one

Comment: @Harry12345 Paste the whole thing into your first post.  Usually the line that says "Caused by" is the one of interest, but it can't hurt to look at the whole stack trace.