# unchecked cast Map <String, String> allPreferences

Tags: java, android, casting, gradle

I have a gradle warning about unchecked cast. The app builds without bugs but I want to clean up any code issues. I saw a similar post here [How do I cast from int to generic type Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705091/how-do-i-cast-from-int-to-generic-type-integer)

It is not clear to me how to check the value for the cast.

```
.../mayday/md/model/SMSSettings.java:56: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        Map<String, String> allPreferences = (Map<String, String>) sharedPreferences.getAll();
                                                                                           ^
  required: Map<String,String>
  found:    Map<String,CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

line 56 `Map<String, String> allPreferences = (Map<String, String>) sharedPreferences.getAll();`

```
public static SMSSettings retrieve(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Map<String, String> allPreferences = (Map<String, String>) sharedPreferences.getAll();
    List<String> retrievedPhoneNumbers = retrievePhoneNumbers(allPreferences);
    return new SMSSettings(retrievedPhoneNumbers, allPreferences.get(SMS_MESSAGE));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that `SharedPreferences` [can contain different objects than just Strings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
If you are 100% sure you have only Strings in your `SharedPreferences` object you can ignore this warning and add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to your method or above line with your casting.

Answer (score 0):

[getAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()) returns a `Map<String, ?>` not a `Map<String, String>`, where the unbounded wildcard `?`, is a short version of  `<? extends Object>`. If I didn't misunderstood you

```
 Map<String, ?> allPreferences = sharedPreferences.getAll();
```

should remove the warning

Comment: This is a good comment. It does not however answer OPs question.

Comment: @blackbelt, thanks for the info, I'm not sure how to use that info to solve the problem.